# Index / Match - Receiving an error when trying to find entry

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, google-sheets-formula, index-match

I am very fresh with Excel and still learning the basics. I came upon an issue I really need help with and couldn't find suitable solution online.

I have a column I keep on constantly updating with Bulk data [THE COLUMN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPch5.png).

I'd like to see the **most common entry** and the **least common entry** for a specific time using this formula:

```
=INDEX('Data Input'!F433:F610,MODE(MATCH('Data Input'!F433:F610,'Data Input'!F433:F610,0)))
```

But once I try it, it constantly tells me:

> Did not find value '' in MATCH evaluation.

I've tried with shorter ranges and It **did work**, so I guess once it runs through empty cell - it breaks. How can I modify this formula to function properly and print what I need?

And side question, is is possible to implement a calendar bar and choose between dates?

Comment: Can you confirm that this is applicable to your tag of 'Excel'? I ask because the error message you give appears to be from Google Sheets, not Excel.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant Google Sheet, I'll edit it immediately.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a clause to exclude blanks (assuming they are not to be considered a legitimate return):

`=INDEX('Data Input'!F433:F610,MODE(IF('Data Input'!F433:F610<>"",MATCH('Data Input'!F433:F610,'Data Input'!F433:F610,{0,0}))))`

Note that I have used

`{0,0}`

for `MATCH`'s *match_type* parameter so that the formula will not error should there be more than one entry within your range which shares the highest frequency. In such cases, the above formula will return that which occurs first in your list.

Comment: Hey Jos, thank you very much for your quick and descriptive response. In order to understand better the functionality, is `'Data Input'!F433:F610<>""` means that it checks whether the cell is empty, and if not it continues with the match formula?

Comment: That's correct, yes.

Comment: This is great, I am delighted to learn this new function!

Is there a way to check the least common value? The opposite of =mode?

Comment: I would really appreciate if anyone can enlight me with opposite of =mode formula

Comment: There are several more concise options available in Excel, though none of them appear to work in sheets, so try `=INDEX(F433:F610,MATCH(MIN(IF(F433:F610<>"",COUNTIF(F433:F610,F433:F610))),IF(F433:F610<>"",COUNTIF(F433:F610,F433:F610)),0))`